# how to fix this my server ip is up and my sites are down

Tags: server, dns

my server ip is up and online and my site is down
the site was up for 2 months and suddenly it's down
the FTP is not working too
how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the ftp ports are not blocked by any firewall. Try a graceful reboot on your server.